# Passing a string into Sweave Rnw file

Tags: errors, r, sweave, environment-variables, variable

I understand from [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6729/supplying-string-parameters-to-sweave-document) that it's possible to push a variable to an Rnw file from the R script that calls it by storing that variable in the global environment within the R script. I've tried to do that but I can't get the Sweave file to recognize the variable.

For example, if I have an R script (say, `test.R`) that looks like:

```
TESTGLOBALVARIABLE <<- "XXXXXXXXXTESTGLOBALVARIABLEXXXXXXXXXXX"
system("R CMD Sweave /foo/bar/test.Rnw"))
```

and `test.Rnw` looks like:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}
\setlength{\TPHorizModule}{30mm}
\setlength{\TPVertModule}{\TPHorizModule}
\textblockorigin{10mm}{10mm} % start everything near the top-left corner
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{textblock}{3}(0,0)
The test global variable is: \Sexpr{TESTGLOBALVARIABLE}
\end{textblock}

\begin{textblock}{2}(2,1)
\textblocklabel{block two}
Here is another, slightly narrower, block, at position (2,1) on the page.
\end{textblock}

\end{document}
```

When I run test.R, I get an error `Error: at test.Rnw:13, object 'TESTGLOBALVARIABLE' not found
Execution halted`.

I've checked similar questions like [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/161249/passing-a-string-from-an-r-script-to-rnw-template-r-code-section-brew-knitr). Is it possible to do this without brew?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some inspiration from nebi's answer, I was able to do it by creating a separate R script `set_vars2.R` written by `test.R`:

If `test.R` is:

```
directory <- "/foo/bar/"
setwd(directory)

file.create(paste0(directory, "set_vars2.R", open = "r"))
fileConn <- file(paste0(directory, "set_vars2.R"))
writeLines(c("TESTGLOBALVARIABLE <<- \"XXXXTESTGLOBALVARIABLEXXXXX\"",""), fileConn)
close(fileConn)

system(paste0("R CMD Sweave ", directory, "test.Rnw"))
system(paste0("pdflatex ",     directory, "test.tex"))
```

and `test.Rnw` is:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}

\setlength{\TPHorizModule}{30mm}
\setlength{\TPVertModule}{\TPHorizModule}
\textblockorigin{10mm}{10mm} % start everything near the top-left corner
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}

<<sourcing_r, include=FALSE, echo=FALSE, results=hide>>=
source("/foo/bar/set_vars2.R")
@

\begin{textblock}{3}(0,0)
The test global variable is \Sexpr{TESTGLOBALVARIABLE}
\end{textblock}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Does it work when you source your file.R?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}
\setlength{\TPHorizModule}{30mm}
\setlength{\TPVertModule}{\TPHorizModule}
\textblockorigin{10mm}{10mm} % start everything near the top-left corner
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}

<<sourcing_r, include=FALSE, echo=FALSE, results=hide>>=
source(file = "/foo/bar/test.R")
@


\begin{textblock}{3}(0,0)
The test global variable is: \Sexpr{TESTGLOBALVARIABLE}
\end{textblock}

\begin{textblock}{5}(2,1)
\textblocklabel{block two}
Here is another, slightly narrower, block, at position (2,1) on the page.
\end{textblock}

\end{document}
```

Comment: If I source the original `"/foo/bar/test.R"` script that calls the `R CMD Sweave` command, obviously it hangs. But I'll try sourcing it from a different R script.

Comment: It works if I remove the `R CMD Sweave` command, but that defeats the purpose. If I create another script (say, `/foo/bar/set_vars.R`) with only the `TESTGLOBALVARIABLE <<- "XXXTESTGLOBALVARIABLEXXXX"` line, that wouldn't work either, because I need to set the value of `TESTGLOBALVARIABLE` within `test.R`, so I can't have it hardcoded in `set_vars.R`. If there is some way to edit `set_vars.R` within `test.R`, that could work. I'll play around with `file.edit()` and see if I can get it to work.